# scheduling a task to run at log on

Tags: windows, windows-7, tcp, operating-system, ip

I would like to send a packet to another machine when my computer is powered on. I scheduled the task as when I log on but my LAN seems to have some sort of checkup and my computer needs to initialize the network stuff before the network really works. Thus, my task can't be run when I log on. Have you any ideas of whether or not my thinking about this is right or something else I need to learn ? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Your "task" has to make sure the destination host (PC) is online and is listening on a specific port. What would you like to send and is there a server running on the other PC?

Comment: You said two different things here. You said "when my computer is powered on", but your title and text say "log on". Which is it? They're two distinctly different times, and two totally different sets of circumstance. (And it should be clear that you can't send a network message without your computer initializing the "network stuff". With no "network stuff", there's no network to send the message across.)

Answer (score 0):

The amount of time it takes for Windows to establish network connectivity is highly variable.  Do you know the IP address of the machine you are trying to talk to?  If so, then I would simply poll that address using SendARP() until it succeeds (or you hit a max number of retries and give up).  Once you get a response to the ARP packet you should be able to communicate.